# MemoryMarshal.Cast ASCII byte to char

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

I have an allocated `Span<byte>` that contains ASCII character bytes and need to cast it to `Span<char>`.

MemoryMarshal.Cast() does seem to do the job but (correct me if I am wrong), the casted span characters are UTF16 encoded. In general what I am trying to achieve is to avoid any extra allocations.

**Edit**

The goal is to be able to parse the ascii characters string without a need of reallocating or copying.

Any potential solutions to this?

Comment: "need to cast it to Span" span of what? `byte`? `char`? Please show code and sample data.

Comment: its a span<byte> an ascii string basically, need to convert to span<char> since most of the string apis only operate on span<char>

Comment: **Please show code and sample data.** You probably need something like `Encoding.ANSI.GetString(yourSpan)`. You can't cast it directly because it's the wrong encoding, `char` is UTF16

Comment: You are correct and I am aware of that BUT this would allocate a new string which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: How do you think to represent a 1-byte characterset in a 2-byte characterset without allocating anything?

Comment: @Ralf you are right and that was the reason I raised the question, it looks like there are new apis in net8 that will allow me to use a pooled buffer and copy/convert the bytes to ascii chars https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.trygetchars?view=net-8.0

Comment: So you don't want to prevent allocation you just want to use something preallocated where you can move your data into? If you look up the sourcecode of the linked methods you will end up [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/Ascii.Utility.cs,8f400d768e10c26e,references)

Comment: @NullReference please [edit] the question to clarfy your requirements. So far the question makes no sense as it complains that `char` is taking 2 byes and somewhat `UTF16` (strictly speaking it is not... but very close, definitely the same for ASCII range 32-127) and request no allocations to somehow fit 2x data into the original memory size...

Comment: C# always handles strings as UTF-16 so you won't get around this if you really want `char`s or `string`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fit UTF16 characters into the same space as ASCII, it's twice as large.

If you want to reduce allocations you can use `ArrayPool`.

```cs
var maxSize = Encoding.ASCII.GetMaxCharCount(yourSpan.Length);
var buffer = ArrayPool<char>.Rent(maxSize);
var size = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(yourSpan, buffer);
var charSpan = buffer.AsSpan().Slice(0, size);

// do stuff with charSpan

ArrayPool<char>.Return(buffer);
```

Comment: Indeed this is a potential way, I guess only other solution would be manually parsing the bytes in the span.

Comment: The new Utf8String feature might be an option when it turns up https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/933 What exactly are you doing with the string anyway?